# In what way is $\chi(M)$ not an isometric invariant?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Isometric invariants relating curvature/integrals of  $ K,k_g$ along with the topological invariant $\chi(M)=( 2-2g) $ or$\,(2-r) $ the Euler characteristic appear on either side of the equation of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem:

[image: GBthm]

So $\chi(M) $ can be expressed in terms derived from isometric invariant Christoffel symbols of first fundamental form.

If so, is $\chi(M) $ an isometric invariant and topological invariant at the same time?

Comment: Can you state (or give a reference to) what is the relation between $\chi(M)$ and the Christoffel symbols? I didn't manage to find it

Comment: I have not calculated it myself but $ \int\int K dA,\, \int k_g ds $ are isometric invariants. We can add them and divide by $2 \pi.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Every isometry is a homeomorphism, then the Euler characteristic is an isometric invariant because it is a topological invariant.

Comment: However in general every homeomorphism is not an isometry. So to me it appears  Euler characteristic is not automatically an isometric invariant in full bijective sense.

Comment: @Narasimham what do you mean by "in the full bijective sense". It is a topological invariant, so a fortiori an isometric invariant.

Comment: @Henno Brandma Please help me understand. Since topological mapping condition is stronger, it goes without saying the special cases of $ K, \chi(M)$ are  invariant in topological maps, Right?

Comment: If $M$ and $M'$ are homeomorphic, $\chi(M) = \chi(M')$. So in particular we get the same conclusion if $M$ and $M'$ are even isometric (this is the stronger condition, in my terminology; it imposes more restrictions).

Comment: The *sum* of $k_g, K$ terms is a topological invariant, but not each term *individually*